# \usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz} --> no output at all

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot

I have a simple test document, that stops working if

```
\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}
```

is included in the preamble. I use TeXnicCenter in conjunction with pdflatex. I wanted to generate a tikz file with gnuplot 4.4.4 (with the gnuplot-tikz.lua file from 4.4.3, because the 4.4.4 version is broken) and then compile it with latex, but as it is now including the necessary package mentioned above suppresses all output. I have copied the file gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty to the same directory as the tex file that I am trying to compile (code shown below):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
Test
\end{document}
```

The above example results in the following on compiling:

> LaTeX-Result: 0 Error(s), 0 Warnings(s), 0 Bad Box(es), 0 Page(s)

If I remove the line \usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}, everything works. How can there be zero errors and also no page output? What do I need to do to get output?

/Jonas

PS: I also want to include a tikz-picture that gnuplot generated, but I have omitted that code (quite long) since I get the same result on compiling -- zero errors and zero pages -- whether I include the picture or not.

PS2: I don't really know what lua is or how it works, so if the answer has to do with lua, I would be grateful if "lua-related stuff" is explained.

Comment: Hi hjb981, I've removed the thanks. It's just the style here, and thanks is best expressed as upvoting those answers that help you.

Comment: It works fine for me. You might try looking at the log file (located in the same directory as your Latex document), and see if it has any complaints.

Comment: I had a look at the log file, and it looked similar to other log files, except that the last parts were missing (i.e., where the MPS to PDF converter gets loaded). I am no expert on this, and I may have missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling MiKTeX solved the issue.

It appears that some part of my MiKTeX 2.8 / TeXnicCenter installation had become corrupt. Yesterday, even old files that I new should compile without problems started to give the 0 error(s) and 0 page(s) result. The MiKTeX maintenance tools did now work as they should either when I tried to "update FNDB" and "reset formats" (I got errors). I ended up reinstalling MiKTeX (in the process I also upgraded from 2.8 to 2.9), and now it works again, including the gnuplot-lua-tikz package.